# What would the corresponding HQL query for this TSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql, hql

I want the TSQL query to be re-written in HQL. Here is the T-SQL query that I want to convert to HQL query. The following T-SQL query works fine.

```
DECLARE @D_Id INT = 120
DECLARE @DR_Id INT = 1100

IF @D_Id <> 120 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        d.D_Name 
    FROM 
        Department AS d 
    WHERE 
        d.D_Id = @D_Id
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        DR.DR_DepartmentOther 
    FROM 
        DataRequest AS DR 
    WHERE 
        DR.DR_Id = @DR_Id
END
```

I want the corresponding HQL query. I have written the following HQL query:

```
CASE
    WHEN D_Id <> 120
        SELECT 
            D.D_Name 
        FROM 
            Department AS D 
        WHERE 
            D.D_Id = D_Id
    WHEN D_Id = 120
        SELECT 
            DR.DR_DepartmentOther 
        FROM 
            DataRequest AS DR 
        WHERE 
            DR.DR_Id = DR_Id
END
```

When I execute the above HQL query I get the following error:

> Error while executing the Hibernate query.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: Why not decide which query to execute in your Java code? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-467 looks like sub-selects are not supported.

Comment: I have to have inline query as I am using it in Reactor (ColdFusion).

Comment: In cases like this I just run the raw SQL using `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CASE
    WHEN D_Id <> 120 THEN 
        (SELECT 
            D.D_Name 
        FROM 
            Department AS D 
        WHERE 
            D.D_Id = D_Id)
    WHEN D_Id = 120 THEN 
        (SELECT 
            DR.DR_DepartmentOther 
        FROM 
            DataRequest AS DR 
        WHERE 
            DR.DR_Id = DR_Id)
END
```